# Bash script to download PDFs stored in a CSV file that includes name and url

Tags: bash, csv, pdf

[Bash script to download PDF using a CSV with name and url and auto-increment name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593711/bash-script-to-download-pdf-using-a-csv-with-name-and-url-and-auto-increment-nam/69594160#69594160)

I was able to find this solution (see link above) that appears to work for me, but am unable to open any of the newly saved PDF files. Here's my code currently (it's basically identical to the solution linked):

```
downloadPDF() {
    LINECOUNTER=0
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2
do
    LINECOUNTER=$[$LINECOUNTER +1]
    if [ "$field1" == "" ]
    then
        echo "Line $LINECOUNTER: field1 is empty or no value set"
    elif [ "$field2" == "" ]
    then
        echo "Line $LINECOUNTER: field2 is empty or no value set"
    else
        pdf_file=$(echo "$field1" | tr '/' ' ')
        echo "================================================"
        echo "Downloading $LINECOUNTER: $pdf_file..."
        echo "================================================"
        pdf_file_saveas="$pdf_file.pdf"
        FILECOUNTER=0
        while [ -e "$pdf_file_saveas" ]
        do
            FILECOUNTER=$[$FILECOUNTER +1]
            pdf_file_saveas="$pdf_file.$FILECOUNTER.pdf"
        done
        if [ $FILECOUNTER -gt 0 ]
        then
            echo -e "\033[32m ^^^ File already exists!!! Adding number at the end of the file: $pdf_file_saveas \033[0m" >&2
        fi
        wget -q -nc -O "$pdf_file_saveas" "$field2"
    fi
done < ./data_duplicates_removed.csv
}
```

I've tried several PDF readers and get the same "unable to open file" error. The links in the CSV file work, so that's not the problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Update:
I have cleaned up the code quite a bit to focus in on the issue, but still getting the same error as before.

```
downloadPDFMod() {
    LINECOUNTER=0
    while IFS=, read -r field1 field2
    do
        LINECOUNTER=$[$LINECOUNTER +1]
        pdf_file=$(echo "$field1" | tr '/' ' ')

        pdf_file_saveas="$pdf_file.pdf"
        wget -q -nc -O "$pdf_file_saveas" "$field2"
    done < ./data_clean.csv
    }
```

This works (I changed the names of the pdfs since they are confidential):

```
wget -q -nc -O "name.pdf" "http://download.pdf"
```

Update 2:
CSV file looks like

```
New_Name, URL, MFG, MPN
ROHS_MFG_MPN, http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/..../acrobatdocument.pdf, MFG, MPN
```

There are over 2,000 lines and each one has a specific MFG and MPN. The New_Name field is populated by a text join that joins ROHS_ with the data in the MFG and MPN fields.

An example line (with names and url changed) is:

```
ROHS_Manufacturer_Name_Manufacturer_Part_Number_123, http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs2.../manual/acrobatdocument-ec2.pdf, Manufacturer_Name, Manufacturer_Part_Number_123
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the pdfs you are trying to download?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. They are confidential documents.

Comment: The script works fine with me, my guess is files might be corrupted. Try installing one of them using `wget -q -nc -O name url` and check if you can open the file.

Comment: That works, but I don't understand why that method does and the other doesn't lol

Comment: For a nonworking download, what does `wget` tell you if you remove `-q` ? What does `file nonworkingfile` tell you? What content do you see if you try `less nonworkingfile`?

Comment: Can you provide some example lines from the csv file, and expected output of downloaded file names? (modify names for privacy, but keep the format representative)

Comment: @dan I posted an update with example CSV data. Sorry it's not more specific.

Comment: @KJ The URLs work when I copy paste them into my browser and when I manually set them as the values in the code. It seems to be more of an issue with the loop since everything works when not using the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input format is as follows,

```
New_Name, URL, MFG, MPN
```

Your problem start with the first loop statement:

```
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2
```

Now that I've said that, you should be able to spot it yourself.

"read" is told to work with only 2 variables to handle all of the input on the input line.

You have not understood that read lumps $2, $3, $4 all into field2.

So ... you are working with **a malformed parameter for field2**, having the spurious info for **MFG** and **MPN** included with your URL in the expansion of field2.  wget doesn't know how to handle that, especially since you added double-quotes to force interpretation as a single value for field2.

You would need to use dummy variables to capture unwanted info.

```
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2 field3
```

or

```
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2 field3 field4 [ ... ]
```